# Sails.js - get previouse url from request

Tags: url, request, sails.js

How can i get previouse url without magic and in backend?

Now i get it through policies:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.session.previouseUrls) {
    req.session.previouseUrls = [];
  }
  req.session.previouseUrl = req.session.currentUrl || "/";
  req.session.currentUrl = req.url;
  req.session.previouseUrls.push(req.session.previouseUrl);

  next();
};
```

but it's uncomfortable. Can i get previouse Url from backend simpler?

Comment: Previous url? Is it the url that client hit before current one? Why do you need to get it?

Answer (score -1):

If you need to know the history (or just previous page) of the user's page requests purely on the client-side, could you query native [HTML5 History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)?

..or if you need to support older browsers, maybe [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)?

I would be concerned with how you're doing it now for 2 reasons:

- It's going to start filling up your session store. This may not be a big issue if you have short-lives sessions or not many users.
- It could record not just traditional page views "clicks" but any request. Unless you're very carful about scoping this policy you may end up adding an Ajax call that goes through this policy check and you probably didn't intend for that.

Comment: I'm only asking about the backend. And yes, I fully understand that any AJAX can break ьн policy. That's why i asлing for help with BACKend solution

Comment: Got it. I understood your question to mean "without magic in backend" and not "without magic, in backend".

Comment: Sorry for that. change this part to "without magic and in backend"